# Extension of injective maps to isomorphism of tensor products

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Suppose we are given two vector spaces $V, W$ of equal dimension over a field $k$, assumed to be of characteristic $0$. $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic for reasons of dimensionality, but suppose we have an additional $k$-algebra $A$ with no zero divisors, and an injective map

$$\iota:V\to W\otimes A.$$

We can easily extend $\iota$ to an $A$-linear map $V\otimes A\to W\otimes A$, that will also be injective. Under what conditions does this define an isomorphism (of $k$-vector spaces)?

For example, if we know $A$ to be finite dimensional, we get an isomorphism of $k$-vector spaces. Does this hold more generally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, it is not true that the extension of $\iota$ to a map $V\otimes A\to W\otimes A$ is always injective.  For instance, if $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is a basis for $W$, then $\iota$ could map two basis vectors of $V$ to $e_1\otimes a$ and $e_1\otimes b$, where $a$ and $b$ are commuting $k$-linearly independent elements of $A$.  Then the extension to $V\otimes A$ would fail to be injective, since $e_1\otimes a$ and $e_1\otimes b$ are not linearly independent over $A$.

If you assume that the extension is injective, then a rephrasing of your question is: if $M=W\otimes A$ is a free $A$-module of finite rank $n$ and $N=V\otimes A$ is a submodule of $M$ that is also free of rank $n$, must $M=N$?  Under your assumption that $A$ has no zero divisors, this is true iff $A$ is a division ring.  In the case that $A$ is a division ring, this is just linear algebra.  On the other hand, if $A$ is not a division ring, pick a nonzero element $a\in A$ with no inverse, and then the submodule of $M=A$ generated by $a$ is a free submodule of rank $1$ which is not all of $M$.